# Different dependency settings for 'Debug' and 'Release' build configuration in VisualC++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, configuration, dependencies, visual-c++-6

I'm using VisualC++ 6.0. (and, yes, I'm using Mosaic browser..;)
My VC++ project has different dependency setting for 'Debug' and 'Release' build configuration.
So, when I switch from one configuration to other, I have to change the dependency 
by hand every time.
Is there any better way to do this? Can I keep my dependency setting according to each configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Which dependency are you dealing with?

Under build, there is a configuration for debug/release/both.

If you can supply more details, I might be able to help.